# Get logs for a HQL statement inside Shell action for a Oozie job

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, oozie

There is oozie job, where one of the shell action has below statements.

```
test.sh
------------
LOCAL_SUB_DIRECTORY=/tmp/data
# create the local directory

mkdir $LOCAL_SUB_DIRECTORY
chmod -R 777 $LOCAL_SUB_DIRECTORY

hive -f testload.hql


if $(hadoop fs -test -d $/user/$get_year/p_zip_directory_date) ; then echo "ok"
echo "do something"
else
echo "do nothing";
fi
```

The requirement is to capture the logs only for the statement "hive -f testload.hql" and store it in the location "/tmp/data" in local or HDFS.

Comment: What are you attempting to capture?  The actual results of the HQL statement? Everything that comes back?

Comment: Nope.. I want to capture the job logs of the "hive -f testload.hql" for the analysis.

Comment: Is it just  `hive -f testload.hql > $LOCAL_SUB_DIRECTORY/hive.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).log` what you are looiking for?. And adding some error handling like `|| { echo "hive-command failed rc=$?"; exit 9; }` would be nice. Do you really want to open up the directory for everybody? Allowing complete (recursive) access for everybody seems to be overkill. What if the directory already exists and isn't yours? Additional checks could be helpful.

Comment: yes.. I want to capture the logs with all types of exceptions for my usecase analysis, where I need to grep lines from the log file with Exceptions/Error/Failed into separate file. The directory belongs to me, once job ran is complete, I will delete the directory.